# How do you properly format a sum of timespans?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a single column list of rows that I pasted into Excel that looks like:

```
1:15
0:25
0:43
```

These represent hours and minutes worked each day. I want to sum up the total and see how many hours I have worked. I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Excel. I know I use the formula:

`=FIRSTCOLUMN+LASTCOLUMN`

The issue is that the column does not seem to be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

h:mm or hh:mm show hours or minutes based on a 24 hour clock. [h]:mm or [hh]:mm will not use a 24 hour clock

Comment: +1 - this is correct `[h]` or `[hh]` will show the *total* number of hours represented by the value in the cell, instead of the number of hours modulo 24.

Answer (score 1):

If you just run a "`=SUM(firstcell:lastcell)`" it should add up hours and minutes properly.
Tried this on Excel and the cells have format: `custom`, "`h:mm`".

Update: Couple of references...

1. [Excel Dates and Times FAQ](http://www.contextures.com/xlfaqdat.html)
2. [Date Arithmetic](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datearith.htm)

Comment: hmm, tried that, it says 0:00 as the result.  I did =SUM(A1:A59)

Comment: (and yes I did convert the entire column to custom h:mm)

Comment: Are you on Excel 2007?

Comment: make sure the cell with the total is also formatted to hh:mm

Comment: This answer is not correct, at least not for my version of office

Comment: As pointed out in another answer, this will only work for sums less than 24 hours.